# make company-backends work in lisp files

Tags: company-mode

I have a running Emacs on my gentoo, with doom configuration (with evil mode disabled).
It works great.
One issue i want to solve...

Some company-backends - for example like `company-files` in Lisp files, do not work.

When I run Emacs and try to enter a path to a load function - nothing happens.
If I do `eval-buffer` on the file that I have the `company-backends` settings - it starts to work.
So it seems that that piece of code runs too late.

Here's what i do:
On my `.doom.d/config.el` file I load my custom el file.
in that file I do

```
(after! company (setq company-backend '(company-files company-capf)) )
```

I also tried to add `(setq company-backends '(company-files))` to the `config.el` file.

None of the above worked.

Comment: Looks like doom has a function to set the backends (and also a variable to define the default backends used): https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/e498a7e2cb66ef1d6305a206a3f3924e4c4501ac/modules/completion/company/autoload.el#L12

Comment: @Hubisan - you're a genius! that worked perfect! Thanks!! - too bad you answered in comment and not a real answer - i'd set it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doom has its own function **`set-company-backend!`** to set the backends:

```lisp
(defun set-company-backend! (modes &rest backends)
  "Prepends BACKENDS (in order) to `company-backends' in MODES.

MODES should be one symbol or a list of them, representing major or minor modes.
This will overwrite backends for MODES on consecutive uses.

If the car of BACKENDS is nil, unset the backends for MODES.

Examples:
  (set-company-backend! 'js2-mode
    'company-tide 'company-yasnippet)

...
```

You can also change the default backends used. They are defined in `+company-backend-alist`:

```lisp
(defvar +company-backend-alist
  '((text-mode company-dabbrev company-yasnippet company-ispell)
    (prog-mode company-capf company-yasnippet)
    (conf-mode company-capf company-dabbrev-code company-yasnippet))
  "An alist matching modes to company backends. The backends for any mode is
built from this.")
```

Those variables and functions are defined in https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/completion/company/autoload.el.

Comment: Great, working perfectly. Thanks!